# Sort OS Listdir With Numbers in String

Tags: python

I have a folder. In this folder are files that look sort of like this:

`'page_121.png', 'page_122_png', 'page_123.png'... etc`

When running this bit of code in Python:

`sorted(os.listdir())`

Something like this is returned:

`'page_276.png', 'page_277.png', 'page_278.png', 'page_279.png', 'page_28.png', 'page_280.png', 'page_281.png', 'page_282.png'`

Notice how it sorts them alphanumerically, but going from 279, it jumps to 28, which makes sense, but is not my desired result. How might I get it so that the array returned is in the order of the numbers smallest to largest, so that `page_28.png` is over in between `page_27.png` and `page_29.png`?

Comment: Are you aware of how to extract a number from a string? If you can do that, pass a function that does it as the `key` argument to `sorted`.

Comment: You can use [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/)

Comment: To the couple below, I'll add `sorted(list, key=lambda s: int(re.sub(r'\D', '', s)))`  This just keys on any digits in the filename, converted to an integer.

Comment: All these answers are working great. As it turns out, it had less to do with file sorting and more to do with natural sorting or human sorting in Python. I've associated the question with with one that already covers that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're sorting strings which, by default, is done in alphabetical order.  Therefore, "279" is going to come before "28".  What you want to do is sort the strings by the integer contained within the string.  To accomplish this, you can do the following.

```py
def extract_integer(filename):
    return int(filename.split('.')[0].split('_')[1])

sorted(os.listdir(), key=extract_integer)
```

Comment: The base string functions should be faster and more efficient than regex +1.

Answer (score 3):

You may sort on the number, cast to an integer, using a lambda:

```
files = ['page_276.png', 'page_277.png', 'page_278.png', 'page_279.png', 'page_28.png', 'page_280.png', 'page_281.png', 'page_282.png']
files.sort(key=lambda x: int(re.sub(r'page_(\d+)\.png', r'\1', x)))
print(files)
```

This prints:

```
['page_28.png', 'page_276.png', 'page_277.png', 'page_278.png',
 'page_279.png', 'page_280.png', 'page_281.png', 'page_282.png']
```

Comment: I gotta get in the habit of using regexes for string extraction.

Comment: Actually, the regex I wanted to use here would be to just extract `\d+` from the filename, but I don't know of any Python API which can simply do that.  So, I'm stuck with the bulkier `re.sub` option above.

Comment: Thanks, this does what I intended it to.